# Subtracting substring from string in as many possible steps

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Goal is to find the maximum amount of times you can subtract t from s.

t = ab, s = aabb. In the first step, we check if t is contained within s. Here, t is contained in the middle i.e. a(ab)b. So, we will remove it and the resultant will be ab and increment the  count value by 1. We again check if t is contained within s. Now, t is equal to s i.e. (ab). So, we remove that from s and increment the  count. So, since t is no more contained in s, we stop and print the  count value, which is 2 in this case.

Problem occurs when you have something as s = 'abbabbaa' t = 'abba'.
Now it matters if you take it from the end or beggining, since you will get more steps from the end.

```
def MaxNum(s,t):
  if not t in s:
    return 0
  elif s.count(t) == 1:
    front = s.find(t)
    sfront = s[:front] + s[front + len(t):]
    return 1 + MaxNum(sfront,t)
  else:
    back = s.rfind(t)
    front = s.find(t)
    sback = s[:back] + s[back +len(t):]
    sfront = s[:front] + s[front + len(t):]
    print (sfront,sback)
    return max(1 + MaxNum(sfront,t),1 + MaxNum(sback,t))
```

Comment: What's your question? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: Please use either the [tag:python-2.7] or the [tag:python-3.x] tag unless your question is specifically about a cross-version compatibility problem. If you are only just learning the basics, you should probably ignore Python 2, and spend your time on the currently recommended and supported version of the language, which is Python 3.

Comment: @Carcigenicate well this code doesnt get all answers correct. And it takes too long. I was doing an exam and couldnt figure out the solution.

Answer (score -2):

```
def foo(t,s):
    return max([0] + [
        1 + foo(t,s[:i]+s[i+len(t):]) for i in range(len(s)) if s[i:].startswith(t)])
```

Should I ask why you care?

Comment: what do you mean if I care?
And, It doesnt have to be at the beginning of the string, and I dont see case for the end.
The problem is subtracting T from S from left or right and getting done with as much steps as possible

Comment: If you think it doesn't work, try to construct a counterexample and run it.  Don't just dismiss it out of hand.